# Mongoose add to array without duplicates and sorted

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongoose

In Mongoose it is possible to add new values to an array without duplicates with $addToSet:

```
Model.update({ _id: elementFromDb._id }, { $addToSet: { array: newElement} }
```

And it is possible to add a new value to the array in correct order (sorted) with $push and $sort:

```
Model.update({ _id: elementFromDb._id }, { $push: { array: { $each: newElement, $sort: 1 } } }
```

But it seems NOT possible to add a new element to the array without duplicates AND sorted because $addToSet dosnt work with $sort...

How can I do this?

Comment: first check whether item of array already exist , if exist then promote error or else push item in array

Comment: how can I check that? I add all array elements asynchr. in parallel...so i cant get the array to check because in the time of checking no elements are available at this moment...

Comment: using findOne() method of mongodb

Comment: sorry but it dosnt work. because of the parallel adding of elements. I need a direct mongoose solution like $push $sort and so on ^^